# How to set header to a string in java using JMS

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to set RFH2Header type to a message string. But it's not appending to the message.
Please help. Thanks in advance!!!!
Is My approach is correct ?? If i check in response queue, RFH Property gets added to bytes message.

```
String message1 = "MQ Message header test";
Message message11 = session.createTextMessage(message1);

MQRFH2 header = new MQRFH2();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
DataOutput dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
header.write(dout);
byte[] outheaders = out.toByteArray();
byte[] bArray = message1.getBytes("UTF-8");
BytesMessage responseMessage = session.createBytesMessage(); // throws JMSException
responseMessage.writeBytes(outheaders);
responseMessage.writeBytes(bArray);
responseMessage.setJMSType("MQRFH2");
responseMessage.setJMSCorrelationID("12345678900000");
responseMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(2);
responseMessage.setJMSPriority(4);
responseMessage.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
responseMessage.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_Format", "MQRFH2"); 
responseMessage.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_Encoding", MQConstants.MQENC_NATIVE); 
responseMessage.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", 1208);
responseMessage.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_PutApplType", 11);
producer.send(responseMessage);
```

My output looks like below in response queue.., Please help , how to set header to a string

```
00000   4D 51 20 4D 65 73 73 61--67 65 20 68 65 61 64 65  |MQ Message heade|
00010   72 20 74 65 73 74 52 46--48 20 00 00 00 02 00 00  |r testRFH ......|
00020   00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00--00 00 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.$........      |
00030   20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00--04 B8                    |  .......�      |
```

Comment: Question is not very clear. Do you want to add RFH2 type of data as body to a JMS message? or set RFH2 type of data as JMS message header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear about the question but in any case the following may be useful to you.

RFH2 is MQ specific while JMS is a standard. A MQ JMS application can not explicitly set RFH2 data as **JMS message header**. MQ JMS client internally sets the required RFH2 headers to build a JMS message while the message is being sent. The application can only set message body and a number of JMS properties using `setJMSxxxx` and user defined properties using `setxxxProperty` methods. For example the snippet below sets a string type property called `MyStringProperty`.

```
responseMessage.setStringProperty("MyStringProperty", "SomeString Data");
```

RFH2 data will be a stream of bytes with a fixed header part and variable data part as described here:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032000_.htm?lang=en. Hence you need to create `BytesMessage` if you want to send RFH2 data as part of **message** **body**.

Comment: Is it possible to alter the answer to also show how to do subkeys in JMS ? trying to use a period to create subkeys like "MyColor.Red" results in an JMSCC0049 exception being thrown. The knowledge center does not show any examples of howto do that.

Comment: Interesting, let me try your scenario when I get to my laptop some time later.

Comment: I too tried setting a property name containing a period and got the same error. According to this documentation in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q001730_.htm, property names must not contain a period. Suggest you to use an underscore instead of period.